# Administrative and secured CMS for storing secret credentials?

Tags: cms, open-source

My boss asked me to setup a secured area online, which will contain all the FTP, MySQL etc details related to our web products. This online area must be secured and will only be accessible by the user we define.

It should be easy to understand and should have functionality to download details in PDF or in word format etc.

And should be able to handle following type of scenario:
A client has 10 websites so we'll need to store FTP, MYSQL etc details related to 10 websites, so CMS should be able to accept and present the data in easy way.

Do anyone has any suggestions for me to handle such kind scenario.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://codecanyon.net/item/ultimate-client-manager/47626) and [this](http://codecanyon.net/item/php-login-user-management/49008).
I think you should write the export functions on your own, though, which is easy anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not a CMS, but [PassPack](http://www.passpack.com/en/home/) seems to be designed specifically for this purpose. [Thycotic's SecretServer](http://www.thycotic.com/products_secretserver_overview.html) is a self-hosted solution. Other alternatives include [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/), [Mitto](http://mitto.com/), and [CloudSafe](https://secure.cloudsafe.com/). [Here's a list](http://alternativeto.net/software/clipperz/?sort=likes&platform=online) of other potential alternatives.